# Navbar highlight for current page

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I would add the ability to add a highlight box the nav bar on the page your currently on. You know so people know what page their on.

Very much like this site with the white box on the active page:https://woodycraft.net/home/

Here is the CSS for my nav bar:

```
/*TOP NAV BAR SECTION*/

*{margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;}

#nav_bar {background-color: #a22b2f;
          box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px;
          height: 45px;
          text-align: center;}

#nav_bar > ul > li {display: inline-block;}

#nav_bar ul > li > a {color: white;
                      display: block;
                      text-decoration: none;
                      font-weight: bold;
                      padding-left: 10px;
                      padding-right: 10px;
                      line-height: 45px;}

#nav_bar ul li ul {display: none;
                   list-style: none;
                   position: absolute;
                   background: #e2e2e2;
                   box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px;
                   text-align: left;}

#nav_bar ul li a:hover {background: #8e262a;}


#nav_bar a:active {background: white;}

#nav_bar ul li:hover ul {display: block;}

#nav_bar ul li ul li a {color: #252525;
                        display: block;}

#nav_bar ul li ul li a:hover {background: #4485f5;
                              color: #fff;}
```

Here is the HTML for one of my pages:

```
<!--TOP NAV BAR SECTION-->

                <div id="nav_bar">
                                <ul>
                                  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="status.html">Status</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>

                                  <li><a href="#">Gamemodes</a>                                      
                                <ul>
                                  <li><a href="survival.html">Survival</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="pure-pvp.html">Pure-PVP</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="gamesworld.html">Gamesworld</a></li>
                               </ul>
                                  </li>                                    

                                  <li><a href="rules.html">Rules</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="vote.html">Vote</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                               </ul>
                           </div>
```

Comment: Add a class (for example 'selected') to your item on your current page and style the particular item :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the same navigation bar in each HTML page of your website, then you can do like this:
For example in **index.html** add **class='active-page'** to the first menu item:

```
<div id="nav_bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class='active-page'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="status.html">Status</a></li>
        <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
```

Then in the **status.html** add **class='active-page'** again but for the second item:

```
<div id="nav_bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="status.html" class='active-page'>Status</a></li>
        <li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
```

And do this for all of your pages.

Finally in your css write a class for **active-page** like this:

```
#nav_bar ul li a.active-page
{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: I get the CSS bit, but I'm confused about the class on the html. I'm new to coding you see

Comment: How you create you navigation bar? It different depends on your language. Is it just HTML? PHP, ASP? you can even highlight the current page with javascript or jquery

Comment: Oh it's all HTML would you like to see one of the pages?

Comment: On that site, active item in the menu has the **navLink** class. you just should try to give this class to one of your items that you want. Language is not important, Its logic is all with your.

Comment: I still don't understand I need to see an example on my own code, i'm a visual learner. I'll add the html code to my post.

Answer (score 29):

You can use the jquery function **window.location.href** to compare the site you are on right now with your **href** of **< a >** in the list element. For example, "index.html":

```
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

The code below searches for the **href** of the active page in the list elements **< a >**. Then adds the class "active" with **addClass('active')** to the active pages **< a >** so that you can now call it via **CSS**. Put this code in the head of your html file.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('a').each(function(){
            if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
                $(this).addClass('active'); $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can now add your css conditions like changing the color:

```
#nav_bar .active {
    color:            #F8F8F8;
    background-color: #4f81bd;
}
```

Comment: Great!, I was exacting looking for this

Answer (score 2):

I somewhere found a pretty simple code to do it.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('nav li a').filter(function () {
            return this.href === location.href;
        }).addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function (){
        $('a').each(function(){
            if ($(this).prop('href') === window.location.href) {
                $(this).css({"background": "linear-gradient(to left, #f58D28 0, #f58D28 66%, #ba5c00 100%)", "border-radius": "30px"});
    
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: I liked the idea thomas0721 had, I had a similar issue and added to it using the jquery css() feature, if your using PHP on your site i.e. you have only one nave that you "include", add this line of code into a separate js file src it in the headers