# HTML/jQuery - How do I dynamically highlight the current page or section?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**What do I want?**
jQuery to dynamically highlight the current page from the navigation bar.

**Am I new to jQuery/HTML?** Yes - apologies if it's a silly question

**Have I spent hours scouring existing StackOverflow posts to no avail?** YES! These have been the most promising but for reasons I don't understand, their suggestions aren't working

- [Navbar highlight for current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819675/navbar-highlight-for-current-page)
- [How to make css a:active work after the click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566238/how-to-make-css-aactive-work-after-the-click)
- [jQuery current page highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761328/jquery-current-page-highlight)
- [highlighting the current page in a list of links using css / html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318170/highlighting-the-current-page-in-a-list-of-links-using-css-html)

**What's the problem?**
Using the code below, I am trying to make the current page(/selected section) in my navigation bar stay highlighted in green (to show the end-user what page they're currently on).

The hover-over functionality is working but I can't seem to get it to stay that colour once I've clicked on it.

FYI - I've used #links and links.html in my "navigation menu" as I want the solution to work for both cases (although in the real thing I'll have two separate menus: one with links to .html pages and one with links to #sections of the page.

**Have I made a small reproducible example?** See below

*index.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test_main.css">
    
</head>

<body>

    <div class="navigation">
        <a href="test.html">Home</a>
        <a href="#section_a">Section A</a>
        <a href="#section_b">Section B</a>  
      </div>

      <script>
          $(function(){
              $('a').each(function(){
                  if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
                      $(this).addClass('active'); $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
                  }
              });
          });
      </script>
            
    <p>Example text</p>

</body>
```

*main.css*:

```
/* Add a white background color to the top navigation */
.navigation {
  background-color: #555555;
  color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.navigation a {
  float: left;
  background-color: #555555;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.navigation a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.active {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  color: #00000
}
```

I know this can be done statically by just setting class="active" in the navigation class but this is too cumbersome and not maintainable.

Comment: Is this a single page application or does clicking a link load an entirely new page?

Comment: Re: is this a single page application:

It is NOT a single page application i.e. sometimes new pages will be loaded but sometimes the navigation will just take the user to a different part of the page (i.e. via a #section) so I awkwardly need the solution to work for both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** - add `navigation a:not(.active)` to the main.css.

Full answer for highlighting of the top-navigation menu based on the page:

*index.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test_main.css">
    
</head>

<body>

    <div class="navigation">
        <a href="test.html">Home</a>
        <a href="#section_a">Section A</a>
        <a href="#section_b">Section B</a>  
      </div>

      <script>
          $(function(){
              $('a').each(function(){
                  if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
                      $(this).addClass('active'); $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
                  }
              });
          });
      </script>
            
    <p>Example text</p>

</body>
```

*main.css*:

```
/* Add a white background color to the top navigation */
.navigation {
  background-color: #555555;
  color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.navigation a:not(.active) {
  float: left;
  background-color: #555555;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.navigation a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.active {
  color: #00000;
  float: left;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  color: #00000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you code is work but for `priority` reason it can't apply the style to replace `.navigation a`, try adding `!important`

```
.active {
  background-color: #00ff00 !important;
  color: #000000 !important;
}
```

to activate on menu with URI fragment/hash you may need to apply `click` event

Comment: Spamming `!important` all over your css is rarely the right answer. And is definitely not the right answer here.